# How to hide RefreshProgressIndicator after onRefresh is called in RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh, showdialog

In my network function I use `showDialog()` to show progress dialog when the network call is happening, but I also need the `RefreshIndicator` to have the pull-to-refresh.

When I pull down on ListView, the `RefreshProgressIndicator` is shown, and when I let go, the `onRefresh` method is called which loads my `networkCall` function which shows my own progress dialog, and the `RefreshProgressIndicator` is still loading behind the progress dialog, which is expected.

So is there a way to hide/stop the `RefreshProgressIndicator` so that it is not loading behind the my progress dialog?

```dart
Future<void> networkCall() async {
   showDialog();
   await apiCall();
   hideDialog();
   setState((){...}):
}

RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: networkCall,
   child: ListView.builder(),
)
```

I need my own `showDialog()` to show the loading process. So how do I hide the `RefreshProgressIndicator` when `onRefresh` is called?

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation said that we have to return Future.delayed.zero to avoid the spinner never go away.

and i think you can use this logic.

```
Future<void> networkCall() async {
  // add this to dissmis the spinner
   Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)); // spinner will go away immediately

   showDialog();

  // you can use await or then,whatever you want.
   apiCall().then((value){ 
   hideDialog();
  });
   setState((){...}):
}
```